# Python Email Parser not reading from text file

Tags: python, typeerror, text-parsing, file-read, email-parsing

I am trying to run the following code for reading the contents of the mail from a text file by using the parse() function of email.parser.Parser but continuously getting error as **"TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'"**

```
from email.parser import Parser

with open('an_email.txt') as fp:
    mail_msg = Parser.parse(fp)

print(mail_msg)
```

I am unable to find a solution to this. Can please someone help on this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parser` is an instance method in the `Parser` class. That means that you must first create a Parser instance:

```
...
parser = Parser()
with open('an_email.txt') as fp:
    mail_msg = parser.parse(fp)
```